# Cannot login to wordpress dashboard. Facing HTTP ERROR 500. Trying t o access it via 000webhost

Tags: wordpress

Everytime I try to login to wordpress on 000webhost, it provides me with the following error:

This page isn’t working
websiteName.000webhostapp.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Please could anyone advise on this issue.

Comment: Please check the .htaccess file , check files permissions must be 644/666, folder permissions must be 755, check admin password should not be weak.

Comment: I checked, tried renaming, didn't work. The permission of the file is 755.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do when troubleshooting the internal server error in WordPress is check for the corrupted .htaccess file.

Comment: .htaaccess file is:    `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: No, it is still showing the same error. If I rename the old .htaaccess file, my website would just load the index page and every other pages would throw a 404 error.

Comment: Go to admin dashboard and set permalink so that other pages will also start working

Comment: I cannot access the dashboard of wordpress.